# Unable to set sql_mode in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I want to set `sql_mode` to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` only.

I modified `my.cnf` and added this line:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

restarted mysql service but when I execute this query:

```
 show variables like '%sql_mode%'
```

that's what I get:

[image]

How can I fix this issue? I am using vps bought via godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set `sql_mode` for the session.

```
 SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

You can verify the setting with the `SHOW VARIABLES` statement.

---

To change the global setting:

```
  SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

---

To have the global setting initialized when the MySQL server restarts, the setting can be configured in the configuration file(s) e.g. `my.cnf`.

I believe that setting needs to be under the `[mysqld]` section of the configuration file.  Note that there may be more than one configuration file being read. There might be a `/usr/my.cnf` file that contains a setting.

The `sql_mode` can also be specified as an option on the mysqld startup command line.

Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' , did that but when restarted the server, it is not more there, seems like there is some configuration that I need to find and modify in one of the config files